# imagecopyresampled cropping black bar

Tags: php, image-processing, crop

I am taking a source image and trying to crop it based on user selection. It always leaves a black empty space though, I am assuming it has something to do with the parameters I'm using in the incorrect order. After looking at php docs for imagecopyresampled() I am still coming up short on a way to make this work.

Here is what I have. I used hardcoded values for the example but each `$targ_` variable changes for each image.

```
$targ_w = 183;      // width of cropped selection
$targ_h = 140;      // height of cropped selection
$targ_x = 79;           // x-coordinate of cropped selection
$targ_y = 59;           // y-coordinate of cropped selection
$targ_x2 = 263;         // x-coordinate of 2nd point (end of selection)
$targ_y2 = 199;     // y-coordinate of 2nd point (end of selection)

$src = '/uploads/test.png';
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$targ_x,$targ_y,$targ_x2,$targ_y2,$targ_w,$targ_h);

$newFileName = '/uploads/test2.png';
imagepng($dst_r, $newFileName, 9);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am just on the wrong path, but Your variable identifiers suggest that You use coordinates where dimensions are needed. The order is _dest coordinates - source coordinates - dest dimensions - source dimensions_

Comment: They are coordinates but technically aren't they dimensions as well since I am taking the x and y of the selection to crop?

Comment: Because the cropped area's dimension (so also scale) should be preserved, both, target dimension and source (=crop area) dimension must be the same. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is just because you did not calculate the crop area's dimensions correctly. Besides that you use coordinates, where dimensions should have been used. Compare parameter seven and eight.
Note that this does not preserve transparency.

```
<?php
$targ_x1 = 59;      // x-coordinate of cropped selection
$targ_y1 = 69;      // y-coordinate of cropped selection
$targ_x2 = 160;     // x-coordinate of 2nd point (end of selection)
$targ_y2 = 82;      // y-coordinate of 2nd point (end of selection)

//1st: dynamically calculate the dimensions
$crop_area_width = $targ_x2-$targ_x1;      // width of cropped selection
$crop_area_height = $targ_y2-$targ_y1;      // height of cropped selection

$image_path = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png';
$src_img = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_area_width, $crop_area_height);

//2nd: cropping does not change scale so source and target dimensions are the same
imagecopyresampled( $dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $targ_x1, $targ_y1, $crop_area_width, $crop_area_height, $crop_area_width, $crop_area_height);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dst_img);
?>
```

Comment: That was it, I was under the impression x2 / y2 had it calculated, apparently I was wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

See below URL:-

[Cropping an image with imagecopyresampled() in PHP without fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005501/cropping-an-image-with-imagecopyresampled-in-php-without-fopen)

try this:-

```
<?php

function load_file_from_url($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $str;
}

class cropImage{
 var $imgSrc,$myImage,$thumb;
 function setImage($image) {
       //Your Image
         $this->imgSrc = $image; 

       //create image from the jpeg
         $this->myImage = imagecreatefromstring($this->imgSrc) or die("Error: Cannot find image!");
         $this->thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 112);

        //imagecopyresampled($this->thumb, $this->myImage, 0, 0, 0, 45, 200, 112, 480, 270);
         imagecopy($this->thumb, $this->myImage, 0, 0, 0, 45, 200, 112, 480, 270); 
    }
    function renderImage()
    {                            
         header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
         imagejpeg($this->thumb);
         imagedestroy($this->thumb); 
         //imagejpeg($this->myImage);
         //imagedestroy($this->myImage); 
    }
}  

    $image = new cropImage;
    $image->setImage(load_file_from_url($_GET['src']));
    $image->renderImage();

?>
```

Comment: There seems to be too many parameters for imagecopy() PHP.net says imagecopy() is
`bool imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )`